# In below sentence what is wrong word in grammar?

Tags: grammar

In below sentence, what is worng word(A~D) in grammar? I don't know what part is wrong(and why).

[image]

Comment: Is either A, B, C or D wrong?

Comment: I have to choose among a, b, c, d. but i don't know what answer is.

Comment: @user4545 It seems like all are correct, but my guess is it's D. It should be "tragic roles", as there are "interpretations", not "interpretation". Others please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I believe @Man_From_India is correct. "Interpretations" is plural, so "tragic role" should be plural also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To formalize Man_From_India's answer - D is wrong, and it should be "tragic roles".

That said, there's another possible correction, with a different meaning: "a tragic role":

"...in her interpretations of tragic roles."
"...in her interpretations of a tragic role."

The first of these is more likely to match what was actually meant: there were many tragic roles she acted in, providing one interpretation to each.

The second can be rephrased as "there was a single tragic role, which she provided multiple interpretations for."

Comment: Stephen, you are absolutely correct. Whether that correction is indeed needed or not will purely depend on the context. I myself when I would give exams found such questions and I always since then believed those are pretty foolish questions.